# python regex need help to enumerate data

Tags: python, regex, findall

I want to enumerate '4.9.8' from this line. how can i get that. i am new in Regex.

```
import re
url  = 'http://variety.com'
line = "<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'https://js-sec.indexww.com/htv/htv-jwplayer.min.js?ver=4.9.8\'></script>"
regex = "?ver=(.+?)\'>"
version = re.findall(regex,line)
print(version)
```

Comment: `?` is a special char in regex that makes the pattern it modifies optional (matches 1 or 0 times). [Escape it, `\?`.](https://ideone.com/xD1UO4)

Comment: @Shivam Raj Please don't update the code in the question according to the answers you got, otherwise the question doesn't make sense anymore - I wondered for a while what the problem was, as I was looking at the corrected code. I rolled back your edit to the original version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `?` special character :

```
import re
url  = 'http://variety.com'
line = "<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'https://js-sec.indexww.com/htv/htv-jwplayer.min.js?ver=4.9.8\'></script>"
regex = "\?ver=([0-9.]+)"
version = re.findall(regex,line)
print(version)
```

Returns :

```
['4.9.8']
```

I used `"\?ver=([0-9.]+)"` regexp but you can also use yours like this : 
`regex = "\?ver=(.+?)\\'>"` (escape `\` too)

Comment: this regex is raising an error `raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 13`

Comment: @ShivamRaj Does not on my computer (python 3.6.4) which version do you use ?

Comment: Nah..thanks it solved my problem.BTW i am also using 3.6.4